# Show the existence of a set $F'$, such that $F \subseteq F'$ and $|F'|=2^{n-1}$!

Tags: hypergraphs

$F\subseteq2^{[n]}$ and it has no disjoint elements in it. Show that exists an $F'\supseteq F$, such that $F'$ still has no disjoint elements and $|F'|=2^{n-1}$!

I tried to construct $F'$ of $F$ fixing one element $a\in [n]$ and taking all subsets of $[n]$ that includes $a$, but clearly if I don't have a special element like that, then my reasoning is not working.

Can you please give me a hint on how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: In the subject you say $|F'| = 2^{n-1}$ but in the body you say $|F'| = 2^{n+1}$... which is it?

Comment: $2^{n-1}$, sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks, I edited it.